# Table caption misplaced and no list of tables generated

Tags: tables, apa-style, rmarkdown

I am writing an APA-style document in RMarkdown  using Papaya package, which compiles into LaTeX, and then to pdf, by pandoc. I know a small amout of LaTeX, and I am not familiar with RMarkdown, and was asked to use it. So I have two problems here, and thank you in advance for any help.  The problems might be related to Rmarkdown/Papaya, but they could also be purely LaTeX related, so even if you don't know about RMarkdown, you may still know something.

**The first problem**. I have the following table in my RMarkdown file,

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    Model & Composability & Unboundness & Comm. & Sync.  & Distribution & Mobility\\ \hline
    $\pi$ & explicit & explicit & shared-mem & sync  & NA & NA \\ \hline
    Join & explicit & implicit & shared-mem & sync & implicit & implicit\\ \hline
    Ambient & explicit & explicit  & shared-mem & sync & explicit & explicit\\ \hline
    Actor & NA & implicit & message-pass & async & implicit & implicit \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \captionof{table}{Summary of Properties of Concurrency Models}\label{summary}
\end{center}
```

I was wondering how I can make the caption one-line and centered in the generated pdf file?

[image]

**The second problem**. I also would like to generate  a list of tables after tables of contents. When I add `\listoftables` to the beginning part of the RMarkdown file together with other LaTeX command, `\listoftables` is missing from the generated .tex file, but the other commands shown below such as `\newcommand` are preserved in the .tex file.

````
```{r analysis-preferences}
# Seed for random number generation
set.seed(42)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(cache.extra = knitr::rand_seed)
```
\listoftables

\newcommand{\defeq}{\vcentcolon=}

\newcounter{equationset} 
\newcommand{\equationset}[1]{% \equationset{<caption>}
  \refstepcounter{equationset}% Step counter
  \noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{Equation set~\theequationset: #1}}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  mathescape
}
````

Then I notice there is an option at the beginning of the RMarkdown file

```
tablelist         : no
```

and I change it to

```
tablelist         : yes
```

but I get the following new compilation warning:

```
Warning message:
Package tocloft Warning: \@starttoc has already been redefined; tocloft bailing
 out. on input line 1147.
```

The LaTeX packages that I included in the RMarkdown file are:

```
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{amsmath}
   - \usepackage{mathtools}
   - \usepackage{listings}
   - \usepackage{caption}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks. It is so moving to be welcomed here. The problems have been driving me so sad.

Comment: Do you have `\usepackage{caption}` in your preamble?

Comment: Yes. Let me add that to my post.

Answer (score 1):

May be try this one in Your main .tex document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm,right=1.5cm,
top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,bindingoffset=0cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{hyperref}  

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoftables
\clearpage

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\chapter{Chapter 2}
\chapter{Chapter 3}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{| c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
    \hline
    Model & Composability & Unboundness & Comm. & Sync.  & Distribution & Mobility\\ \hline
    $\pi$ & explicit & explicit & shared-mem & sync  & NA & NA \\ \hline
    Join & explicit & implicit & shared-mem & sync & implicit & implicit\\ \hline
    Ambient & explicit & explicit  & shared-mem & sync & explicit & explicit\\ \hline
    Actor & NA & implicit & message-pass & async & implicit & implicit \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{Summary of Properties of Concurrency Models}\label{summary}
\end{center}
     
\end{document}
```